# Change url/state on beforeunload using history.replaceState

Tags: jquery, html

I've looked for answers to this one, couldn't find one, I wonder if it's a bug, it seems browsers have bad support for this HTML5 function..

I have only chrome and firefox to test. (latest stable versions).

```
$(function(){
if ( window.history.state != null ) $( "#content" ).html( window.history.state.value );
$( window ).bind( "beforeunload", function() { window.history.replaceState( { value:"remember me"}, "", document.location.href + "?param=rememberme" ); });
});
```

Just try it. I was trying to change the current url on beforeunload, so I can keep data information in the url, so that when the user returns back to the page he will reload the page with the changed url thas has info in it.

But it behaves weirdly on page reload.
First off in chrome `window.history.state` doesn't even exist (not yet supported?), so the state cannot be fetched on reload. And on page reload the url change is not remebered.
But if you go to another site and come back the url change is remebered.

in firefox `window.history.state` exists and on page reload or history forward/back, the state is fetched correctly. But the url change doesn't work on page reload, the url changes correctly every 2 reloads. If you go forward/back the url change will be correctly handled.

Anyone knows how to make that code work properly for page reloads(F5) and if chrome really still has no support for `history.state`? 
Is the behaviour correct on page reload, or are the browsers not handling it well?

If anyone can test it on Safari, I'd be curious to know how it works there.

Just test the code there: http://www.braikar.com/stuff/test.html

Comment: It appears to work fine every time in Firefox for me, but in the others (Safari, Opera, Chrome) it changes the URL in history but the content 'remember me' is not added to the div. In IE it doesn't work at all - no surprise there then!

Comment: One good site to take note of with HTML 5 is http://html5test.com/ - it doesn't appear to be that good with history but there are many other things there that you may need to know at some point. Edit: Now I see what you mean about it working in Firefox on every 2nd reload, I was only checking when clicking the link.

Comment: I'm not even bothering with IE.. I was expecting that it wouldn't work ;) I'm making a cms system quite ahead of time and that's why I just want to understand if that history behaviour is correct or if it's the browsers that are not yet implementing it well. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history that behaviour should work properly on page reload, because I'm changing the state before the page reloads..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a cookie to store your variable?  You could set it in beforeunload and read it on load.